# GTM + GA4: iOS app not sending events to GA4 using GTM

Tags: ios, flutter, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

My app is white-labeled app, we have a single source code, and based on few configurations will publish the app to different customers.
Customers can configure events(tags and triggers) in containers using GTM and these events will go to the customer's analytics account.

This process is working well with Universal Analytics.
Now when I upgrade Universal analytics to GA4, I am not seeing GA4 event type while configuring the tags and I am seeing only the firebase option(attached screenshot), I have selected that and still not receiving events in the customer's account. [image]

For web, while creating tags we are seeing GA4 options(attached screenshot)
[image]

Please help me to upgrade to GA4 or share any documents which works for GTM+GA4+iOS

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there's no GA4 tag is because they made it so easy to [connect](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en) firebase data to ga4. Also to avoid making developers reimplement their app analytics. Connecting Firebase to GA4 is how people implement app tracking for GA4 out there.

GA4 took the whole data structure from Firebase. As the result, FB data fits GA4 tables perfectly. The only reason for GA4 really is the superior UI bells and whistles as well as further data export capabilities.

So you don't need to change anything in your GTM or in your firebase sdk. You do all needed in your firebase ui.

One more thing. Mobile GTM, in most cases, adds more complexity than it solves, so it became an industry standard to not implement it at all.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you should verify that you have set up Google Analytics 4 in your Firebase project, and that you have linked your Firebase project to your Google Analytics 4 property.

Next, you'll need to make sure that you are using the latest version of the Firebase/Google Analytics SDK for iOS in your app. You can find instructions for installing and configuring the SDK in the Firebase documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start

Once you have the SDK installed and configured, you'll need to make sure that you are properly logging events in your app. You can find more information about how to do this in the Firebase documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events

I hope this information is helpful and gets you on the right track.